# Return the smallest key with multiple smallest value in a dictionary in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose

```
d = {1:2, 2:2, 0:2, 3:3}
```

This will return `0`.

How can I do it in one line in python.

Comment: Are you able to expand one what exactly you need to achieve? I don't fully understand what you're trying to do

Comment: `min(d, key=lambda x: (d[x], x))`

Comment: Why is it required to be on one line? Do you have a solution that is multiple lines? This seems like a completely arbitrary constraint

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga since I want to pass as a parameter in command line testing.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thank you so much for the solution!

Comment: @ddttdd or you could literally just do ```min(d)``` since ```min``` will look at the keys in your dictionary rather than their values.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi If you read the Title of the question, then we can assume that he wants the key-value pair, with the combined lowest value. Though I understand the confusion, due to the not-so-detailed example of `d`.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Ah mb, you're definitely right!